# Enabling Google Platform APIs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam

I am a total GCP noob - I've literally just signed up to use one of the APIs.

I tried to follow these steps from [here](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/quickstart-client-libraries) , but got stuck when trying to enable the APIs.

I came across [this](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/getting-started), which tells me: You need permission `serviceusage.services.enable` on the project and permission `servicemanagement.services.bind` on the API to enable it.

There is a link with information on it, but this means nothing to me. I have managed to find and IAM & Admin page for my project, but can't find a way to do the above.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: How did you get stuck in the step of enaling the api (step 3)? you just need to select your project and press the enable button. Since you mention that you just signed up I asume that you are using the owner account. You shouldn't need to follow the second documentation

Comment: You will have the needed permissions if you are the project owner or editor (which will be the case if you created the project). Make sure that the console shows the correct project in the drop down at the top of the page, and that you have accepted the terms of service and enabled billing. Not every API requires billing to be enabled, but many do. That's true even if you are using a free trial.

Then you should be able to use the console to select APIs & Services/Dashboard from the menu on the left side of the page, then click Enable APIs and Services to search for, select, and enable APIs.

Comment: I managed to click around the website until I found a button that it let me enable it. I think it hadn't fully verified my billing - even though it told me it had... lol

Answer (score 0):

To enable the API on you GCP project follow the steps :- 
I. Go to dashboard 
II. From Navigation Menu go to "API and Services" dashboard and then click on “Enable API and Services” 
III. Search for the APIs you need to enable(Cloud IOT, Dataflow API, Cloud Pub/Sub) 
IV. Then click on enable API   

From "IAM and Admin" page you get the service credentials key or json key which enables you to access you gcp project from command line interface.  
To get the service credentials key follow the steps :- 
I. Go to the link for getting service key : https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/serviceaccountkey  
II. Under the heading of “Service Account” select a new service account and then give a name to your service account and select the role as owner{Project<Owner}. 
III. Under the key type select JSON and click on ‘Create’ 
IV. A file will be automatically downloaded on your device.